# how many times is the println statement executed

Tags: java, loops

I kind of don't get the nested loops, can someone explain to me why the following code is executed 45 times please? Shouldn't the i++ and j++ increment by 1? So first loop should be (0 * 0), (1 * 1), (2 * 2) and so on.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.println(i * j);
```

Comment: Have you tried running the loop yourself with pen and paper? Use a table to keep track of the values for `i` and `j`.

Comment: Or use a break point and debug if you don't want to waste a paper...

Comment: @Abishek clearly this is someone who would benefit from a pen and paper approach.

Comment: if you wanted (0*0), (1*1), you would set j and i in the same for loop, thus only needing 1 forloop

Comment: I just gave another approach... No offences meant...

Answer (score 2):

outer loop runs `i` times according to value of `i`

1st i value is `0` last `i` value is `9` because `i<10`.

so inner loop loops `9*10/2` which is `45`

loop time=`0+1+2+.....+8+9` = `9*10/2` = `45`

note . i used this equation to calculate sum of the loop times

```
   1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how nested loops work, its like this -

1. First we enter outer loop, then we execute inner loop till the inner loop exits (that is j's value becomes equal to i) , and only after that we again increment i.

So for example , if `i` is 5 , it would enter the the outer loop, and then `j` would start from `0` till `4` (as i is 5) and the values calculated would be `(5*0) , (5*1) , (5*2) , (5*3) , (5*4)` , and after exiting the inner loop, it would again increment `i` by `1` , `i` would then become `6` and then this would repeat (that is j would start from 0 till 5).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than printing out the expression `i * j`, print out the values of `i` and `j` so you can trace through and see whats happening in the loops.  The product of `i * j` is really meaningless to understand how many times it loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.println("i " + i + "j " + j );
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you have a problem in understanding the scope of variables. I am re-writing the code for better understanding:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            System.out.println(i * j);
        } //end of scope of variable j
}// end of scope of variable i
```

You are most probably mistaken that at the end of the second loop when `i` stores the value of 1 the variable `j` should store the value of 1. But that is not the case. The variable `j` is reinitialised to the value of 0. So when the `i` attains the value of 2 in the 3rd loop the inner loop is executed 2 times for value of `j` as 0 and 1. and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already explain the loops I won't do it. But if you make your code output a little more information, you can more easily see what happens.

```
public static void main( final String[] args )    
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "outerloop: i = " + i );
            System.out.println( "___________________________" );
            for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            {
                System.out.println( "innerloop: i = " + i + " & j = " + j );
                System.out.println( "Counter: " + counter + " calculation: " + i + " * " + j + " = " + ( i * j ) );
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println( "___________________________" );
        }
    }
```

This is how I did it in school to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int iCount=1;
        System.out.println("Outer for loop will begin and run for 10 times");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("    Inner for loop will begin and run for " + i + " time(s)");
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.println("        (" + iCount + ") Inner for loop running....." + (i * j));
                iCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Outer for loop ends");
```

Output :-

```
Outer for loop will begin and run for 10 times
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 0 time(s)
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 1 time(s)
        (1) Inner for loop running.....0
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 2 time(s)
        (2) Inner for loop running.....0
        (3) Inner for loop running.....2
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 3 time(s)
        (4) Inner for loop running.....0
        (5) Inner for loop running.....3
        (6) Inner for loop running.....6
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 4 time(s)
        (7) Inner for loop running.....0
        (8) Inner for loop running.....4
        (9) Inner for loop running.....8
        (10) Inner for loop running.....12
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 5 time(s)
        (11) Inner for loop running.....0
        (12) Inner for loop running.....5
        (13) Inner for loop running.....10
        (14) Inner for loop running.....15
        (15) Inner for loop running.....20
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 6 time(s)
        (16) Inner for loop running.....0
        (17) Inner for loop running.....6
        (18) Inner for loop running.....12
        (19) Inner for loop running.....18
        (20) Inner for loop running.....24
        (21) Inner for loop running.....30
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 7 time(s)
        (22) Inner for loop running.....0
        (23) Inner for loop running.....7
        (24) Inner for loop running.....14
        (25) Inner for loop running.....21
        (26) Inner for loop running.....28
        (27) Inner for loop running.....35
        (28) Inner for loop running.....42
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 8 time(s)
        (29) Inner for loop running.....0
        (30) Inner for loop running.....8
        (31) Inner for loop running.....16
        (32) Inner for loop running.....24
        (33) Inner for loop running.....32
        (34) Inner for loop running.....40
        (35) Inner for loop running.....48
        (36) Inner for loop running.....56
    Inner for loop will begin and run for 9 time(s)
        (37) Inner for loop running.....0
        (38) Inner for loop running.....9
        (39) Inner for loop running.....18
        (40) Inner for loop running.....27
        (41) Inner for loop running.....36
        (42) Inner for loop running.....45
        (43) Inner for loop running.....54
        (44) Inner for loop running.....63
        (45) Inner for loop running.....72
Outer for loop ends
```